# why can't i access twitter api even putting the right keys?

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

I'm not able to access the twitter API with tweepy. I've already checked and the keys are correct. I'm trying to use version 2 of the twitter api as version 1 is being deprecated. My guess is that the essential access was extremely limited, as I saw several videos on youtube and people were trying to use methods like the one in the code below with the basic API access.I don't know what the real problem is. Can someone help me?

```
import tweepy
import keys

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=keys.BEARER_TOKEN,consumer_key=keys.API_KEY,consumer_secret=keys.API_SECRET,
                       access_token=keys.ACCESS_TOKEN,access_token_secret=keys.ACCESS_SECRET)

print(client.search_recent_tweets('python'))
```

```
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
```

tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

Comment: Well, have you created a project via the developer portal…?

Comment: yes. still this error continues